# How to print a value in single line using shell command?

Tags: shell, groovy

I have written a shell script in a groovy function which should return the the output (in a single line) as `abcd-def-chart` but, I am getting the output as shown below in 2 different lines:

**abcd-def

-chart**

My groovy code:

```
String getChartName(Map configuration = [:]) {

    if (configuration.chartName != null) {
        return configuration.chartName
    }

    chartName = ""

    if (configuration.buildSystem == 'maven') {
        chartName = getMavenProjectName() + "-chart"
    }

    echo "chartName: ${chartName}"

    return chartName
}

String getMavenProjectName() {
    echo "inside getMavenProjectName +++++++"
    def mavenChartName = sh returnStdout:true, script: '''
    #!/bin/bash
    GIT_LOG=$(env -i git config --get remote.origin.url)
    basename "$GIT_LOG" .git; '''
    echo "mavenChartName: ${mavenChartName}"
    return mavenChartName
}
```

Comment: remove unnecessary space-chars with trim() function: `return mavenChartName.trim()`

Comment: Thanks for your time. It's working.